# Clients Unable To Connect To Server Or Database

Tags: linux, sql-server-2008

We recently moved several of our servers and VMs from one location to another. We have already go through and set up DNS and given all the correct IPs for all the machines we needed but we have one southware application that is throwing an error when we try to launch the application:

A System.ServiceModel.FaultException error Occurred while attempting to start SouthWare.
Message: Server was unable to process request. --->Failed to update
database "dbName" because the database is read-only.

I went into the database and made sure the db was read write and all the comments calling the db have the necessary rights but still getting that error.

Also through the oracle client I get the ORA-12545TNS:name lookup failed error. I went into our linux server and the made sure the listener was started and active but to be honest, I'm not very experienced with Linux. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you need any more info or need something clarified let me know in the comments bellow and I'll get that to you asap. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused, is the database Oracle or MSSQL?  If Oracle, have you updated the tnsnames file?

Comment: We have an Oracle server and a MSSQL server as well. We're getting off the Oracle server but at the moment we have two. I have not, how do I do that in Linux?(Our Oracle Server has a Linux OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux ES release 4.)